Make the integers output by `\int-div-sound: nn` uniformly use either the forward or backward method instead of rounding
Is there any way to make the integers output by \int-div-sound: nn uniformly use either the forward or backward method instead of rounding?

As we known, the output of \int-div-sound: nn {1} {3} is 0, \int-div-sound: nn {2} {3} is 1, \int-div-sound: nn {3} {3} is 1, \int-div-sound: nn {4} {3} is 1...


I want to output 1 from \int-div-sound: nn {1} {3}, 1 from \int-div-sound: nn {2} {3}, 1 from \int-div-sound: nn {3} {3}, and 2 from \int-div-sound: nn {4} {3}...


You probably mean \int_div_round:nn? The round operator of the l3fp module will give you more flexibility, I’d think.

there is no \int-div-sound you would avoid such errors and make your question understandable if you included a complete small document which shows the problem that you are having.

if you do not want rounding, do not use the ..._round command?

\int_div_truncate (which rounds towards zero?

Yes I used a translate website to translate my question from Chinese to English, and then the website accidentally changed _ to -.

@Skyrmion ah. I did wonder how you could make that so consistently, OK:-)

You probably mean \int_div_round:nn, don't you?
The functionality you ask for is already available with the help of l3fp, because you simply want ceil.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \skyrmion_int_div_roundup:nn
 {
  \fp_eval:n { ceil(#1/#2,0) }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testdiv}{mm}
 {% for testing
  \skyrmion_int_div_roundup:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\testdiv{1}{3}

\testdiv{2}{3}

\testdiv{3}{3}

\testdiv{4}{3}

\end{document}


Alternatively:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \skyrmion_int_div_roundup:nn
 {
  \int_eval:n
   {
    \int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {#2}
    \int_compare:nF { \int_mod:nn {#1} {#2} == 0 } { +1 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testdiv}{mm}
 {% for testing
  \skyrmion_int_div_roundup:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\testdiv{1}{3}

\testdiv{2}{3}

\testdiv{3}{3}

\testdiv{4}{3}

\end{document}

Of course, in either case you should specify what to do with negative numbers.
